# Recieve a image in facebook bot messenger using php

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

This is my sample code where I get the message from the user. It's text only, so how can I get if I receive an image from the user? I'm using PHP from my bot.

```
 $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
```

Answer (score 0):

get the value of attach file using php:

$message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['attachments'];

to post the result => $message[0]['payload']['url'].

Answer (score 0):

You will have the image url at:

```
entry[0].messaging[0].message.attachments[0].payload.url
```

To check if you have recieved a text or an image :

```
if(entry[0].messaging[i].message.text)
  //text
else 
  // image
```